# Pandas: how to add each row of a column the value with each other

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, bokeh

[csv file with for each date the earning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuoXY.png)

In the image you see a csv file, I want to add for each date, in the example 01-01-2020, the earnings of that date witch eachother and also for the other date, so an example for 01-01-2020 is the total earnings 11.50. So i can use in bokeh on the x-axis the date and on the y-axis the total amount of that date. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the groupby to obtain what you described

```
df('date')['earning'].sum()
```

Comment: df.groupby('date')...

Comment: Yes, if you only have 1 other column in the df, but better to include it in case more columns are added later IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Something like might work:

```
>>> date = ['01-01-2020', '01-01-2020', '02-01-2020', '02-02-2020','03-02-2020','03-02-2020']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'earning': earnings, 'date': date})
>>> df
   earning        date
0     10.0  01-01-2020
1      1.5  01-01-2020
2      6.4  02-01-2020
3      5.4  02-02-2020
4      7.8  03-02-2020
5      9.7  03-02-2020
>>> df.groupby(['date'])['earning'].sum()
date
01-01-2020    11.5
02-01-2020     6.4
02-02-2020     5.4
03-02-2020    17.5
Name: earning, dtype: float64
```

You could then use the `plot` function on the resulting dataframe from `sum` operation.

Comment: i am going to try it, thank you!

Comment: and how can i put the date on the x-axis and the sum earning on the y-axis in bokeh

Comment: Not sure about bokeh, but using pandas you can try out this - `df.groupby(['date'])['earning'].sum().plot()`. But before that you would have to run - `import matplotlib.pyplot`

Comment: Now the code line sum all de earnings of the same day. How can is sum the earning not per day, but per month?

Comment: Same csv file (with multiple same days), but expanded with months, which goes from January to November.

Comment: I think in that case, you will have to create a year and month column ( given that you might have multiple years of data ) and then do a groupby like above.

Comment: ok, do you also know how i can count the rows, so for example 01-01-2020 has 2 rows, so the output will be the same as above but dor the earnings is not the sum of the earnng but the total rows for that date.

Comment: If you want to get the counts of each data, you can replace `sum()` with `count()` in the `groupby`, i.e. `df.groupby(['date'])['earning'].count()`